# HDIV cipher tag not working

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, hdiv

I'm trying to cipher a parameter using HDIV's cipher tag. I have tried the example from the following page https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/wiki/05.-HDIV-Tag-Libraries#5113-tag-cipher.

According to the documentation

```
<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="<hdiv:cipher parameter="p1" value="v1"/>"/>
```

Should give the result

```
<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="0"/>
```

However I am getting

```
<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="v1"/>
```

And nothing is ciphered/hidden away.

Is there a piece of configuration that I need?

I am using **HDIV 3.2.0**

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the `<hdiv:cipher>` tag inside a form? For example a `<form:form>` tag in Spring MVC.

The cipher tag is designed to add new parameters to an existing form, so you have to include it inside a form tag.

Another thing to check is `confidentiality` configuration option inside Hdiv configuration. If it is disabled, you won't get the confidential value `0` but the real value `v1`.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. I think my problem was that I was trying to use cipher for something else than what it was built for.